# Cannot import X

Tags: python, import

Tenho dois ficheiros dentro de um projeto dos quais um tem o import do outro e vice versa, neste caso o `main_server.py` tem o import `from Servidor.skeletons.Threads import Thread` para conseguir criar uma instância da class Threads e no `Threads.py` tem o import `from Servidor.skeletons.main_server import Server`, para conseguir através do server modificar o atributo `self._server = server`. No entanto, provavelmente devido à redundância dos imports, não consigo correr a main dando o seguinte erro:

> File
>   "C:\Users\rosin\Desktop\SD_PROJ\ByR\Servidor\skeletons\Threads.py",
>   line 5, in
>
> from Servidor.skeletons.main_server import Server
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Server' from
>   'Servidor.skeletons.main_server'

Como não vejo outra forma de as classes conseguirem aceder entre si, dei por mim, em voltas e voltas sem nunca consertar o erro. Em baixo estão os ficheiros em questão.

**main_server.py**

```
import socket

from Servidor.dta_server.main_server import MainServer

from Servidor.sockets.sockets import Socket

from Servidor.skeletons.Threads import Thread

class Server(Socket):

    def __init__(self, port: int, server: MainServer) -> None:

        """
        Creates a client given the dta_server dta_server to use
        :param port: The math dta_server port of the host the client will use
        """

        super().__init__()
        self._port = port
        self._server = server

    def add(self,a,z):
        self._server.addPlayer(a,z)

    def run(self) -> None:
        current_socket = socket.socket()
        current_socket.bind(('', self._port))
        current_socket.listen(1)
        print("Waiting for clients to connect on port", self._port)
        keep_running = True
        while keep_running:
            self.current_connection, address = current_socket.accept()
            last_request = False
            thread = Thread(self)  # worker()                         **import needed here**      
            print("Client", address, "just connected")
            thread.start()
        current_socket.close()
        print("Server stopped")
```

**Threads.py**

```
import queue

import threading

import Servidor.dta_server

from Servidor.skeletons.main_server import Server

from Servidor.sockets.sockets import Socket



class Thread(threading.Thread, Server):

        def __init__(self, socket: Socket) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.socket = socket
        self.work_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.daemon = True
        self.name = ""
        self.avatar = ""




    def addPlayer(self):
        lenght = self.socket.receive_player_size(1)
        lenght = int(lenght)
        #print("Recebido tamanho do jogador",lenght)
        a = self.socket.receive_player(lenght)
        self.name = a
        z = self.socket.receive_avatar()
        self.avatar = z

        #Recebido da forma nome.avatar então é feito o split para adicionar na clase jogador
        result =  self.add(a,z)        **import need to access add method on main_server.py**

        #print("result",result)


    def worker(self)->None:
        print("Worker",self.work_queue)
        while True:
            comando = self.work_queue.get()
            if comando == Servidor.dta_server.ADD_OP:
                self.addPlayer()

            elif comando == Servidor.dta_server.MOVE_OP:
                self.movePlayer()

            self.work_queue.task_done()



    def run(self) -> (bool, bool):
        request_type = self.socket.receive_command(9)
        keep_running = True
        last_request = False
        print("Chegou aqui")
        print(request_type)
        if request_type == Servidor.dta_server.ADD_OP:
            self.work_queue.put(request_type)
            print("queue",self.work_queue)
            #self.work_queue.join()
            self.worker()

        elif request_type == Servidor.dta_server.MOVE_OP:
            self.work_queue.put(request_type)
            #self.work_queue.join()
            self.worker()

        elif request_type == Servidor.dta_server.STOP_SERVER_OP:
            last_request = True
            keep_running = False

        self.work_queue.join()
        return keep_running, last_request
```

Já verifiquei os imports diversas vezes mas estão corretos o erro dá-se após a compilação.

Answer (score 1):

Isso mesmo  - é um caso clássico de "importações circulares". Python tenta fazer a coisa mais intuitiva possível com importações, mas ele tem seus limites.

**tl;dr:** O seu módulo `main_server`  só precisa do nome `Thread` quando a classe for instanciada e estiver rodando, não quando a classe é declarada. Simplesmente mova a linha de importação respectiva:

```
from Servidor.skeletons.Threads import Thread
```

para o final do arquivo, depois da definição da sua classe.
Isso se realmente for precisar dessa importação aí, por que não achei nenhum uso de `Thread` nesse arquivo. Se for o caso,   simplesmente remova essa linha.